# Python: Cannot gunzip file made with gzip

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I'm exploring file compression options, and am confused by the behavior of the gzip module in Python. I can write a gzipped file like this:

```
with gzip.open('test.txt.gz', 'wb') as out:
 for i in range(100):
  out.write(bytes(i))
```

But if I then run `gunzip test.txt.gz` the output (`test.txt`) is still binary. What am I missing?

Comment: When i run your sequence of commands i get text ... all on one line `0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899`

Comment: @MatthewStory it sounds like your default Python is 2.7. You're living the dream!

Comment: Provided a good answer for 3.x. I'm on 2.7 on my mac and 3.5 on my servers ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this works properly in Python 2.7:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('test.txt.gz', 'wb') as out:
 for i in range(100):
  out.write(bytes(i))
```

In Python 3, we have to do:

```
import io, gzip

with gzip.open('test.txt.gz', 'wb') as output:
  with io.TextIOWrapper(output, encoding='utf-8') as writer:
    for i in range(100):
      writer.write(str(i))
```

Comment: This `io.TextIOWrapper` is an unnecessarily complicated way to get to a bytestring in 3.x. (removed my accidental downvote, and provided an alternate answer)

Answer (score 0):

While the code you posted for 2.7 works fine, A simple way to fix this for 3.X would be:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('test.txt.gz', 'wb') as out:
 for i in range(100):
  out.write(str(i).encode("utf-8"))
```